# PayPal Subscription Sandbox Testing

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I am working on paypal subscription which i implemented almost all the part of `txn_type` but i need to check quickly with sandbox mode, if i set the subscription as 1 day then i wait for one day with `completed/failed/eot/` is there a way to test altogether quickly with sandbox mode of paypal. I am not sure waiting for 1 day is the normal behaviour of sandbox mode of paypal? I want to test the paypal with all `txn_type` quickly (everything in one day).

Thanks,

vicky